# Advanced key mapping with keyup instead of keypress in CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

CodeMirror has a lot of ways to alter and define key bindings, but I haven't found a way to alter a single key so its event is fired on `keyup` instead of `keypress`.

What I'm looking for is following scenario:

My `tab` key will be a modifier key for keyboard shortcuts, so for example I can do `tab+q`, while I know how to attach an event in CodeMirror so it fires when that combination is hit (event `keyHandled`), I'm struggling to alter the default behavior when hitting keys.

1. For each key but `tab` I'd like the `keypress` to be fired
2. When `tab` is pressed and hold, nothing should happen
3. When `tab` and a defined key is hit and hold (for example `tab+q`), the event for that binding should fire - but only once, so far even if I managed to catch `tab` event and hold the key, it would just fire the event multiple times
4. If `tab` is hit and released it should insert a tab char

Any ideas on how to approach this? Any other than hacking CodeMirror itself?

JSFiddle example would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do this with the built-in keymap system, since that is defined to only work with the standard modifier keys (shift, ctrl, alt, meta).

But you can track the position of Tab yourself, and add a bunch of extra key bindings that only take effect when tab is down. This isn't perfect (if tab is pressed or released while your document doesn't have focus, you won't notice). See http://jsbin.com/ihunin/428/ for an example. Returning CodeMirror.Pass is a way for a key handler to indicate that it did nothing, and other handlers for the key can take a turn.

Comment: Thanks Marijn, this gets me closer to the final solution (still need to implement the insertion of a tab on keyup). I'm actually working on the new JSFiddle and decided on going with TAB as the modifier key, as you can see not the easiest way to go, but I believe it'll be worth it.